# How to get the root node in xml using jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a 1 xml file with a different parent node. The node created dynamically.

Here's the sample nodes;

1st content:

```
<error code ='0'><id>1234</id><message>ERROR PROCESS</message></error>
```

2nd content

```
<name>
<lastname>Doe</lastname>
<firstname>John</firstname>
</name>
```

just to identify the parent node. please help.. ;(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    var xml = "<name><lastname>Doe</lastname><firstname>John</firstname></name>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
        $title = $xml;

    console.log($xml.find("*").eq(0));
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4e2kH/7/)

if you want to get the root node name then you can use the `nodeName` property

```
console.log($xml.find("*").eq(0)[0].nodeName);
```

Answer (score 5):

Since JQuery 1.9 you can use the :root selector instead of getting ALL the nodes, so:

```
$(xml).find(":root")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [parseXml](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) and [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) documentation:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
alert($xml.contents()[0].nodeName);
```

When filling `xml` with your example XML documents, it should show *error* or *name*. I know it is not the best jQuery code, but it should give you a nice example to start with.

Use this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QsEKt/) to add other XML document to try it.